$\eta= f(y,z) dy \wedge dz + g(x,z)dz \wedge dx +z^2(x^2+y^2) dx \wedge dy$. Find $\int_M \eta$, $M= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: z = x^2+y^2<1\}$
$f, g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ are functions of class $C^1$. We describe a differential 2-form:
$$\eta = f(y, z) dy \wedge dz \ + \ g(x, z) dz \wedge dx \ + \ z^2 (x^2 + y^2) dx \wedge dy$$
Calculate $\int_M \eta$, where M is a part of paraboloid:
$$M = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ : \ z = x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$$
oriented in such way that in every point $p \in M$ the third component of the vector normal to M consistent with the orientation is negative.

Solution:
I can see that the set $M$ defined by $x^2 + y^2 < 1$, $0 < z < 1$, is kind of a bowl as presented below:

Red colour means: $z = x^2 + y^2$
Mint colour means: $z = 1$

I get that:
$$d \eta = d \left( f(y, z) dy \wedge dz \ + \ g(x, z) dz \wedge dx \ + \ z^2 (x^2 + y^2) dx \wedge dy \right)$$
$$d \eta = d \left( f(y, z) dy \wedge dz \right) \ + \ d \left( \ g(x, z) dz \wedge dx \right) \ + \ d \left( z^2 (x^2 + y^2) dx \wedge dy \right)$$
$$d \eta = \frac{z}{2} (x^2 + y^2) dz \wedge dx \wedge dy  = \frac{z}{2} (x^2 + y^2) dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$$
We look for a set for which it is true that: $\partial G = M$. It looks like that set is equal to:
$$G = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ : \ x^2 + y^2 \leq z, \ 0 < z < 1 \}$$
Therefore, form Stokes theorem, we can say that:
$$\int_{M} \omega = \int_{G} d \omega = \int_{G} \frac{z}{2} (x^2 + y^2) \ dx dy dz$$
To solve such integral we can use such parametrization:
$$x = r cos \alpha, y = r sin \alpha, z = h $$
using those, our set is described by: $\{ (r, \alpha, h) : r \in [0,1], \alpha \in [−π, π], h \in (0, 1) \}$
Jacobian of such parametrization is equal to $r$, so we can write that:
$$\int_{G} \frac{z}{2} (x^2 + y^2) \ dx dy dz = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \frac{h}{2} \left( (r cos \alpha)^2 + (r sin \alpha)^2 \right) \ r \ d \alpha \ dr \ dh = $$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} h \ r^3 \ d \alpha \ dr \ dh = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \int_0^1 2 \pi \ h \ r^3 \ dr \ dh $$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 2 \pi \ h \ \frac{1}{4} \ dh = \frac{1}{2} 2 \pi \ \frac{1}{2} \ \frac{1}{4} = \frac{\pi}{8}$$
As pointed in the comments, here I calculated a solid cylinder...

For paraboloid I will need different order of integration:
$$d \eta = \frac{z}{2} (x^2 + y^2) dx \wedge dy \wedge dz = \frac{z}{2} (x^2 + y^2) dz \wedge dx \wedge dy$$
I will integrate over $z$ going from $0$ to $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. Then I will parametrize the circles. Therefore, we have:
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 \int_{r^2}^1 \frac{1}{2}z r^2 r \ d z \ d r \ d \alpha = $$
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} r^3 \int_{r^2}^1 z \ d z \ d r \ d \alpha = $$
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} r^3 \cdot \frac{1 - r^4}{2} \ d r \ d \alpha = $$
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 \frac{r^3(1 - r^4)}{4} \ d r \ d \alpha = $$
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 r^3 - r^7 \ d r \ d \alpha = $$
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{8} \right) \ d \alpha = $$
$$ \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{32} \ d \alpha = $$
$$ = \frac{1}{32} \cdot 2 \pi = $$
$$ = \frac{\pi}{16}$$
Now I feel it's correct (the bounds of integration).

Use the divergence theorem.

Looks wrong. How did the paraboloid suddenly become a cylinder? Also: the way this $M$ is written ignores the disk that caps the paraboloid at $z=1,.$ Without that we cannot apply the divergence theorem.

https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info

The integration bounds $\textstyle\int_0^1\int_0^1\dots dr,dh$ are wrong. You are integrating over a solid cylinder instead of the paraboloid you depicted.

To be precise: the upper bound of $r$ is wrong.

@KurtG. now I think it's correct

Ok, I get it - wrong range of $r$ and $r$ is needed under the integral as an jacobian of parametrization. But why do we go from $0$ to $r^2$ with $z$, and not from $r^2$ to $1$? @KurtG.

Using my boundries I get $\frac{\pi}{16}$ and I think that mine are correct. Yours may be correct as well, but it would need to evaluate to $\frac{\pi}{16}$ in my opinion (maybe there is some error in calculations) @KurtG.

Yes. Your method and $\frac\pi{16}$ are now correct.
